Problem Java jar: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I have developed an application in Java version 8 which has to be executed using a Jar
It starts with the following class:
public class DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit {
    
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        //Verificamos que se pasen tres argumentos
        if (args.length < 4) {
            log.warn("Uso: java Main <idAplicacion> <ruta_certificado> <clave_certificado> <entidad>");
            return;
        }
        
        //Primer argumento: La identificación de la aplicación
        String idAplicacion = args[0];
        //Segundo argumento: ruta al archivo de certificado
        String rutaCertificado = args[1];
        File certificado = new File(rutaCertificado);
        //Tercer argumento: clave del certificado
        String claveCertificado = args[2];
        //Cuarto argumento: entidad (debe cumplir con la expresión regular [0-9]{8})
        String entidad = args[3];
        String patronEntidad = "[0-9]{10}";
        
        //Validamos que el argumento "entidad" cumple con la expresión regular
        if (!entidad.matches(patronEntidad)) {
            log.warn("Error: La entidad debe ser un string de 10 dígitos (ejemplo: 1234567890).");
            return;
        }
        
        //Verificamos si el archivo de certificado existe y es un archivo
        if (certificado.exists() && certificado.isFile()) {
            log.info("Identificacion de la aplicacion: " + idAplicacion);
            log.info("Ruta del certificado: " + rutaCertificado);
            log.info("Clave del certificado: " + claveCertificado);
            log.info("Entidad: " + entidad);
            
            //Llamamos al Servicio descarga de mensajes
            DescargaMensajesEntrada entrada = new DescargaMensajesEntrada();
            entrada.setIdAplicacion(idAplicacion);
            entrada.setFicheroP12(rutaCertificado);
            entrada.setPasswordP12(claveCertificado.toCharArray());
            entrada.setIdEntidad(entidad);
            
            String respuesta = descargaMensajesEntidades(entrada);
            
            log.info(respuesta);
            
            
        } else {
            log.warn("El archivo de certificado no existe o no es un archivo válido.");
        }
        
    }
    
    private static String descargaMensajesEntidades(DescargaMensajesEntrada entrada)  {
        String respuesta = "";
        
        try {
            DescargaMensajesEntidadesReturn response = new DescargaMensajesEntidadesReturn();
            DescargarMensajesEntidadesService descargarMensajesEntidadesService = new DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl();
            response = descargarMensajesEntidadesService.ejecutar(entrada);
            
            respuesta = response.getRespuestaCorrecta().getOut();
            
            if("".equals(respuesta) || respuesta == null) {
                respuesta = response.getError().getTexto();
            }
        } catch (DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault_Exception e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            log.error("Problemas en el servicio de Descarga de mensajes, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return respuesta;
    }

}

If I run it directly (adding the Input Parameters) it works perfectly.
But when I export it in an executable .jar (which will work in other environments) I run it like this:

java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=CERTLEXNET.p12
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=8ba73c7240 -jar palex.jar "PALEXWS" "/certificado/CERTLEXNET.p12" "8ba73c7240" "2807906202"

The following error occurs:

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown
Source)
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown
Source)
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown
Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.executeHandshake(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:350)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:318)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.lambda$null$0(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:104)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:284)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:516)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.upgradeTls(InternalExecRuntime.java:195)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:173)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:113)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:147)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:174)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:123)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.descargarmensajes.LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.llamarWS(LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.java:184)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.descargarmensajes.LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.getLoginServiciosGeneral(LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.java:66)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.service.DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.loginServiciosGeneral(DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.java:106)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.service.DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.ejecutar(DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.java:62)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.inicio.DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.descargaMensajesEntidades(DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.java:74)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.inicio.DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.main(DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.java:57)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
Source)
... 36 more

I don't know if it has to do with Java versions since the jar was generated with jdk1.8.0_231 and in CMD when I run java -version it tells me jre1.8.0_431
Can you help me?
Thank you very much.

possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Note that there are many similar questions. At least one of them should help you resolve your problem.

In most cases, and in this case, commands and error output should be formatted in a [code block] rather than a quote block. And an editor can't really correct the formatting if newlines have been added by the OP, as in this case.
